# Loop through a python List and append items to a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to loop through the list `acteuse` , count the actors in the list and write the actor as index and the count as value into a pandas series.
That code works with writing in a python dictionary, I'd like to try out with pandas series

unique_actor - python set
acteuse - python list

```py
actorcount = pd.Series()
for act in unique_actor:
    count = 0
    for count_act in acteuse:
        if act == count_act:
            count += 1                  
    actorcount.append(count, index = act)
```

This code causes two problems:

1. TypeError: append() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'
   without index:
2. TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object

Thanks in advance for any advice

Answer (score 0):

Usually appeding data to a Series / DataFrame object is not the best pattern, if it can be avoided. In your case, as your start by creating an empty Series object, you may be able to avoid this.

You should try to compute the list of counts values first (in plain Python) that will be in your Series objects and then instantiate it.

This could give something like :

```py
my_series_data = []
for act in unique_actor:
    count = 0
    for count_act in acteuse:
        if act == count_act:
            count += 1
    my_series_data.append(count)

series = pd.Series(data=my_series_data)
```